# How to manually acknowledge message from using Spring JmsListener

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I am using JMS with Spring's JmsListener. I am able to consume messages from a JMS queue, but it is using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`. How can I set `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE` so that I can consume the other message only after that acknowledgment.

```java
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(t -> {
        logger.info("An error has occurred in the transaction");
        logger.error(t.getCause().getMessage());
    });

    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency("4");

    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}

@JmsListener(destination = "QUEUE_1", containerFactory = "myFactory", concurrency = "2")
public void receiveImgGenerationMessage(String transaction) {
    logger.info("message received in queue " + transaction);
    //I will call other api to process the message and do some operation 
    //after the message is processed 
    //I have to Acknowledge the message is processed
    //so that i can consume the other message for process.
}

// jmsTemplate bean
public void sendmessage() {
    for (int i =0 ; i < 10 ; < i++) { 
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("QUEUE_1", i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `setSessionAcknowledgeMode` method on your 
`org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` instance to set [`CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html?#CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE) mode, e.g.:

```java
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {

    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(t -> {
        logger.info("An error has occurred in the transaction");
        logger.error(t.getCause().getMessage());
    });

    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrency("4");

    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}
```

This is discussed in the [Spring JMS JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html):

> The listener container offers the following message acknowledgment options:
>
> - "sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" (default): This mode is container-dependent: For [`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html), it means automatic message acknowledgment *before* listener execution, with no redelivery in case of an exception and no redelivery in case of other listener execution interruptions either. For [`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html), it means automatic message acknowledgment *after* listener execution, with no redelivery in case of a user exception thrown but potential redelivery in case of the JVM dying during listener execution. In order to consistently arrange for redelivery with any container variant, consider "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode or - preferably - setting "sessionTransacted" to "true" instead.
> - "sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE": *Lazy* message acknowledgment during ([`DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)) or shortly after ([`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html)) listener execution; no redelivery in case of a user exception thrown but potential redelivery in case of the JVM dying during listener execution. In order to consistently arrange for redelivery with any container variant, consider "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode or - preferably - setting "sessionTransacted" to "true" instead.
> - "sessionAcknowledgeMode" set to "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE": Automatic message acknowledgment *after* successful listener execution; best-effort redelivery in case of a user exception thrown as well as in case of other listener execution interruptions (such as the JVM dying).
> - "sessionTransacted" set to "true": Transactional acknowledgment after successful listener execution; *guaranteed redelivery* in case of a user exception thrown as well as in case of other listener execution interruptions (such as the JVM dying).

You could also use this in your Spring Boot `application.properties`:

```
spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode=CLIENT
```

Comment: Shall i override like this using jms.listener property `spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode=client` ? ,  Will this work ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I updated my answer to address this point.

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram, thank you for your Answer! is there a way to override this behavior, so we acknowledge manually (call message.acknowladge() method) the broker after we finish all our business logic? In my case I want the message to be removed from the queue not only after I successfully consume it from the queue, but after I finish all the processing in the spring application.  
Thank you.

Comment: @BSL, you should use "CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" as described in the answer. As the Spring documentation states this will give you, "Automatic message acknowledgment after successful listener execution..." If you perform all your processing in the listener then the message will be acknowledged once it completes successfully. There will be no need to call `message.acknowledge()`.

Comment: Thank you @JustinBertram! In my case, I musing Apache Camel JmsComponent that invokes spring JMS template. I don't have control over the Listener so is there a way to override the default Listener used by the JmsTemplate (org.springframework.jms.config.AbstractJmsListenerContainerFactory). Thank you!

Comment: nither this "factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);" 
Nor 
pring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode=client
working for me. Please share any git hub link of spring boot project.