# How to force redelivery of JMS message

Tags: java, spring-jms

I'm writing a service which receives JMS messages from ActiveMQ and calls other services via HTTP. Because HTTP connection may fail I need try to process these messages later. How can I do it? Is it enough just throw exception in the listener?

My listener looks like:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${topic-name}")
public void listen(SomeEvent event) { 
  try {

    // do work

  } catch (Exception e) {
    // is it enough to rethrow exception here?
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this is better answer on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069782/how-to-manually-acknowledge-message-from-activemq-using-spring-jmslistener

Comment: Then you should up-vote that answer and close this question.

Answer (score 1):

As already wrote here: [How to manually acknowledge message from ActiveMQ using Spring JmsListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60069782/how-to-manually-acknowledge-message-from-activemq-using-spring-jmslistener)

I need to configure DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory like this:

```
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Or just specify

```
spring.jms.listener.acknowledge-mode: CLIENT
```

in the application.yml